# Spool is not working properly in SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, spool

```
spool 'D:\\feb_2020.csv';
set embedded on;
set head on;
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
SET NEWPAGE 0;
SET PAGESIZE 0;
SET FEEDBACK OFF;
SET ECHO OFF;
set HEADING ON;
set UNDERLINE OFF;
set colsep ',';
set trimspool on;
set linesize 1000;
select id  from table; 
spool off;
```

I am using this script to save all id info in a csv file from a table. But the problem is no heading of column name is showing in the csv file. I change SET PAGESIZE value, but it insert column name after every  mentioned PAGESIZE number. Actually i want heading name only once.

Comment: Version of SQL Developer?

Comment: You could set `pagesize` to a high number (up to 50000 allowed); but you should consider using `set sqlformat csv` instead of `colsep`, which will give the output you appear to be aiming for from the other settings. That works from 4.1; before that there's a `/*csv*/` hint. [Read more](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/05/formatting-query-results-to-csv-in-oracle-sql-developer/)

Comment: version : 18.3.0

Comment: setting pagesize to 0 is causing the headers to not print at all...bump pagesize higher, so Alex has you on the right path

Answer (score 1):

To spool using Oracle Sql Developer , reference path of the query is required instead of query.

```
@test.sql
```

And `test.sql` will contain:

```
select id  from table;
```